# Postgresql stored procedure : Querying with null and array parameters

Tags: java, sql, arrays, postgresql

I am attempting to search a set of records in my database based on user submitted criteria, using a stored procedure. (Connection through java).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION logsearch( v_log_type text[], v_user_id varchar(32))
RETURNS refcursor as $$
DECLARE
ref refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN ref FOR SELECT * FROM tb_logs 
    WHERE (tb_logs.log_type = $1 OR $1 IS NULL)
    AND (tb_logs.user_id ilike $2 OR $2 IS NULL)
    RETURN ref;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How do I iterate though the `types` provided by user??